# How can I convert PDF to Flash for the web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, pdf2swf

This code below is used in my code behind to upload a .pdf file then convert it into a .swf(flash). The  `WriteToFile` method saves the pdf to the server directory and is called in the `Button1_Click` method. In the `Button1_Clicked` method I created a process to execute the pdf2swf.exe  that was installed with the swftools suite that converts pdf to flash readable form.

However, the downloaded pdf is not being converted to swf, which I want to use to display to my site's users in a non-downloadable form. I already know how to display the flash file (.swf), but need help with conversion.

```
private void WriteToFile(string fileName)
{
    // Create a file

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/");           
    // string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    int fileLength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[fileLength];
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + fileName);
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pageNumber = 1;
    string inputfile = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string filename = @"Sports_Events.pdf";
    WriteToFile(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string outputfile = @"pdfdoc.swf";
    System.Diagnostics.Process pdf2swfprocess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    // Process pdf2swfprocess = new Process();
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pdf2swfprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF2SWF/pdf2swf.exe");
    //pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = inputfile + "-o" + outputfile;
    pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF2SWF/FONTS") + "\"" + " -p " + pageNumber + " " + filename + " -o " + filename + pageNumber + ".swf";
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {

        try
        {

            pdf2swfprocess.Start();

            pdf2swfprocess.WaitForExit();
            pdf2swfprocess.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            Error1.Text = "Error converting file";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Error1.Text = "The selected file does not exist";
    }
}
```

Related Links:

1. [This link attempts the same pdf to .swf conversion](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2008/03/14/convert-pdf-to-swf-in-asp-net.aspx)
2. [This is a link to the tool pdf2swf tool that is installed with the swftools version 0.92 which i installed to do the conversion](http://www.swftools.org/download.html)
3. This person figured out how to get it to work but i don't understand how to make such changes: [SWFTools' pdf2swf: No text converted if started from IIS-hosted website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137401/swftools-pdf2swf-no-text-converted-if-started-from-iis-hosted-website?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried to do it manually first? Have you debugged the flow? Do you get any exceptions? Kindly _elaborate_ on what's going wrong.

Comment: The pdf file is downloaded and my asp.net application executes the pdf2swf converter however it does dont convert the pdf to swf at all which i need to be done in my asp.net app's root directory. If i run the pdf2swf tool independent of my asp.net app it actually converts the pdf to flash (swf) which i intend to display for the web. The asp.net app actually executes the pdf2swf.exe which i copied to my applications directory, however  no conversion is being done

Comment: There are no execptions generated by the code. my application executes. There is a fileupload control on my .aspx page. along with a button to upload the pdf to the app's root directory (which works fine). The button triggers the code behind Button1_Click function above, but no execption is thrown and no conversion done

Comment: It doesn't look like pdf2swf.exe is meant to run on a server.

Comment: But using the pdf2swf.exe to convert the code was achieved by others and it did run on a server. See my related links above